# Nested explicit definitions

Tags: nested, j

For the sake of argument, let's say I want the following program:

```
foo =: monad define
  bar =. dyad define
    x * y
  )
  bar/ y * 2 3
)
```

Ideally, for input `3`, this would yield `54`. However, when putting this into the console, the first of the two `)`s is treated as the ending for the first `define`. Is there any way to prevent this? I want to avoid an inline verb, like `monad def 'x * y'`. My actual verb example is more complex than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not have nested multiline definitions as there is no check for the contents of the definition. The definition ends and **saved** on the first encounter of `^)LF`.

> a multiline body is a script terminated by a solo right parenthesis, so we cannot have one such body inside another.

There are (messy) ways to go around this, for example by forming strings and evaluating them:

```
foo =: monad define
 str =. 'x * y'
 bar =. 4 : (str,:'')
 bar /y * 2 3
)
foo 3
54
```

Maybe forming a **helper adverb** is a better idea.

(**edit**) Example by defining `bar`'s body separately:

```
bar_body =: 0 : 0
  c=. x + y
  c * y
)
foo =: 3 : 0
  bar =. 4 : bar_body
  bar/y * 2 3
)
foo 3
135
```

Comment: How about a verb with multiple lines? E.g `c =. x+ y` then `c * y`, for example.

Comment: That's what the `(str ,: ...)` part is for: `(line1 , line2, ... ,: linen)`. For single lines  you would just `bar =. 4 : str`.

Comment: @Eelvex - Can you provide an example of how a helper adverb could be defined to avoid evaluating a string?

Comment: @Dane, I meant a helper adverb specific to OP's problem. I suspect that the need for this nested verb stems from the need to define the verb from some parameters. Well, that's what adverbs are for.

Comment: Actually, the terminating ) can have leading and trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

The nested terminating ')'s are problematic, but this could work

```
foo =: monad define
bar =. 4 : 'x * y'
bar/ y * 2 3
)

   foo 3
54
```

> Multiple lines in bar definition could just be consecutive boxed
>   strings.

```
foo =: monad define
bar =. 4 : ('t=.x * y';'t+1') NB. parenthesis required
bar/ y * 2 3
)

   foo 3
55
```

Answer (score 0):

The absence of nested blocks was an intentional design decision.

The idea is to put pressure on the developer to name blocks. (And, more generally, there's some significant pressure on the developer to favor concise, simple code.)

That said, adverbs (and conjunctions) can be used to tie blocks together.

Comment: Do you have any citation for the intentionality of the absence? I would think it to be quite odd to restrict what the programmer can do on the basis of design.